# Transitions for sliding navigation using materializecss?

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

Hi I am trying to add  transitions to sliding navigation but in vain. When I click on About Us I takes me to that part immediately. Instead I want it to slide and display. And same for other links as well (Team,Contact). Have a look over below jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/samson421/90zku52x/2/

```
  <div class="navbar-fixed">
   <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper light-blue darken-3" >
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo right-align" >&nbsp;&nbsp;hello.com</a>
       <ul class="left-align">
        <li><a href="#about" >About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#team">Our Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="v_index.php">Login</a></li>
       </ul>       
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <section id="about">
    <div class="container">
     <h4 style="text-decoration:underline;text-align:center">About Us</h4><br><br>
      <div class="quot">
        <h5 style="color:#446CB3;padding-top:30px">Vision</h5>
        <p id="vision">some text</p>
        <h5 style="color:#446CB3">Mission</h5>
        <p id="vision">some text</p>
        <h5 style="color:#446CB3">Objectives</h5>
        <p id="vision">some text</p><br><br><br>
     </div>
  </div>
</section><br><br><br><br>

   <section id="team">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="center-align">
       <h4 style="text-decoration:underline">Core Team</h4><br><br>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col s4">
             <img class="circle responsive-img" src="index2/img/works/1.png" class="circle" height="200" width="200">
                <h5>one </h5>
                <p style="text-align:justify">
              some text
                </p>
                 <div class="row">
                  <a href="v_details.php" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Details</a>
                 </div>
           </div>

          <div class="col s4">
                 <img class="circle responsive-img" src="index2/img/works/2.png" class="circle" height="200" width="200">
                 <h5>two</h5>
                 <p style="text-align:justify">
              some text
                </p>

                <div class="row">
                  <a href="v_details.php" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Details</a>
                </div>
          </div> 

          <div class="col s4">
                <img class="circle responsive-img" src="index2/img/works/3.png" class="circle" height="200" width="200">
                <h5>three</h5>
                <p style="text-align:justify">
             some text

              <div class="row">
                <a href="v_details.php" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Details</a>
              </div>

          </div> 

        </div>
```

```
<div class="center align">
   <h4 style="text-decoration:underline">Contact Us</h4>

      <p>Let us know if you are interested in knowing more.</p>

      <table>


          <tr>
            <td id="no">+4917655434285 </td>
          </tr>



          <tr>
            <td id="email">Email:<a href=">info@hello.com</a></td>
          </tr>

      </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
$("li a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top}, 400);
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L3nxgem6/)

Comment: Hey I see its working but I dont understand why the contact page is scrolling so fast? Its really fast. How can I set equal time?

Comment: Increase the time it should take to scroll. In my answer I set it to `400` millisecond as u can see. Increase it and it should work for u :) Let me know if u have any further issues :)

Comment: Hey thanks man. Any idea how can I highlight the active tab while scrolling?

Comment: That feature is usually called scrollspy. [This could help you](http://materializecss.com/scrollspy.html) since you are using materilizecss :)

Comment: Yes right. Thank you. But I see it is using a vertical navigation list but I have a horizontal list.

Comment: It should still work as long as u add the required class to the navigation element for the scrollspy :)

Comment: Hey you know what. Actually scrollspy function is just enough to get this work done.

Comment: Indeed, which is why I said `It should still work as long as u add the required class` :P

Comment: Hey is there any way if I could change the vertical line in scrollspy function to a horizontal line under the nav list. For ex: http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/NqbarV